# Bizarre shutdown on a very specific task

Tags: cpu, power-supply, gpu, shutdown, debug

I stumbled upon a program (OPENFACE offline facial landmark detector) that shuts down (hard power off) my computer within 20 seconds. Obviously this is not that programs' fault- I experienced same problem (although alot less reproducibly) during VR gameplay and when doing 3D rendering. This doesn't seem to be related to cooling or PSU overcurrent protection (i upgraded both and even though CPU still gets pretty hot during peak synthetic load, it is mostly well controlled, and i have now plenty of headroom on my PSU). Even more surprisingly, with FurMark, I can push my machine up to 130W on CPU and 200W on GPU for indeterminate time and it holds up pretty nicely, but once I start OpenFace,- it is game over within 20 seconds. In my latest experiment I started FurMark CPU burner and let it run for awhile. As expected, it performed well. Then, while FurMark was running, I started OpenFace and my computer was still ok for several minutes. This was unexpected but once I shut off FurMark, my system powered off within seconds. Check out this pic from the last moment before shutdown

[image]

full video

https://photos.app.goo.gl/cxGj2wbWxwGPFHZPA

These things eliminate the issue:

- Having max CPU power limited to 80% in windows power management.
- Having CPU pre-loaded with some CPU-heavy task like FurMark CPU
  burner at full throttle.

Comment: Hard shutdown or soft?

Comment: super hard. power off with a relay click in PSU